# how to use $scope inside .on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm very new to Angular js and am testing a few functions with a simple data-parser project [(Plunkr)](http://plnkr.co/edit/9GtvFt5Kbvn1Sb98AXrA?p=preview). Right now, I'm having trouble accessing $scope variable within a jQuery on click event. I would like to keep some elements hidden until an image is clicked. While I can set `ng-hide` to true within the controller, $scope does not appear to work inside an on click handler. Please help.

### zodiac.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div id="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div>
            <h1>What Animal Are You?</h1>
            <div id="selectPicture"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="zodiac" ng-hide="disappear">
            <h1>Your Zodiac</h1>
            <div id="your-zodiac">
            </div>
            <br>
            <h1>Avoid these Animals</h1>
            <div id="hateDiv">
            </div>
            <br>
            <h1>These Are Your Besties</h1>
            <div id="loveDiv">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

### scripts.js

```
function d(c) {
    console.log(c)
}

var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('zodiac.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.disappear = true //WORKS HERE
        $scope.animalsData = data
        angular.forEach($scope.animalsData, function(item) {
            $('#selectPicture').prepend('<img src="' + item.picture + '" alt="' + item.animal + '">')
        })
        $('#selectPicture').on('click', 'img', function($scope) {
            $scope.disappear = false //DOES NOT WORK HERE
            $('#zodiac div').empty();
            findZodiac(this.alt, "#your-zodiac", true);
        })

        function findZodiac(animal, e, test) {
            angular.forEach($scope.animalsData, function(item) {
                if (item.animal == animal) { //look for the right object 'item', when found, get the image
                    //item.picture
                    $(e).prepend('<img src="' + item.picture + '">')
                    if (test == true) {
                        loveHate(item.hate, "#hateDiv")
                        loveHate(item.love, "#loveDiv")
                    }
                    return
                }
            })
        }

        function loveHate(array, e) {
            angular.forEach(array, function(value) { //loops through an array, get each animal
                findZodiac(value, e, false)
            })
        }
    });

})
```

Comment: `').on('click','img',function($scope)` should be just `').on('click','img',function()`

Comment: I think you should use `$(document).on()` instead of `$('#selectPicture').on()`

Comment: Just use one from outer scope

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion you should not do DOM manipulation directly when using `AngularJS`. Use the directives provided by `AngularJS` instead. Here are the template and controller code if you do so -

### zodiac.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
    <div id="container" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div>
            <h1>What Animal Are You?</h1>
            <div id="selectPicture">
                <img ng-repeat="animal in animalsData"
                     ng-src="{{animal.picture}}"
                     alt="{{animal.animal}}" 
                     ng-click="disappear=false; findZodiac(animal)" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="zodiac" ng-hide="disappear">
            <h1>Your Zodiac</h1>
            <div id="your-zodiac">
                <img ng-src="{{selectedAnimal.picture}}" alt="{{selectedAnimal.animal}}" />
            </div>
            <br>
            <h1>Avoid these Animals</h1>
            <div id="hateDiv">
                <img ng-repeat="animal in selectedAnimal.hate"
                     ng-src="{{animal.picture}}"
                     alt="{{animal.animal}}" />
            </div>
            <br>
            <h1>These Are Your Besties</h1>
            <div id="loveDiv">
                <img ng-repeat="animal in selectedAnimal.love"
                     ng-src="{{animal.picture}}"
                     alt="{{animal.animal}}" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

### scripts.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.animalsData = [];
    $scope.selectedAnimal = {};
    $scope.disappear = true;

    $scope.findZodiac = function(animal) {
        $scope.selectedAnimal = animal;
    };

    $http.get('zodiac.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.animalsData = data;
    });

});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because of using the angular way

Comment: thanks this was helpful, but the images aren't showing for the love/hate divs. Instead of the image url and alt tag I get `<img ng-repeat="animal in selectedAnimal.hate" alt class="ng-scope">`

Comment: i assumed here that `selectedAnimal.hate` and `selectedAnimal.love` are arrays containing animals with the same data structure as `$scope.animalsData`. If they differ, then you have to modify the code accordingly.

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you could edit your question and include sample of `zodiac.json`

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS **$scope** is a global variable for your controller, You don't need to pass it like this. directly use it as

```
$('#selectPicture').on('click','img',function(){
  $scope.disappear=false;//this will work
  $('#zodiac div').empty();
   findZodiac(this.alt,"#your-zodiac",true);
})
```

Comment: No. `$scope` is not global. It's just accessible inside app.controller function (or as long as Angular passes it as an argument in a function)

Comment: even I wanted to say same thing, **$scope is a global variable for your controller,**

Answer (score 0):

check this [corrected version](http://plnkr.co/edit/d9s7tBrfaeCLi75fbOrQ?p=preview)

```
scope object only available in angular world.
```

Comment: Though this solution works, you should explain that this isn't the 'angular-way'